# Why do airlines flag passengers?

Tags: airlines

On my last flight  some guys next to me, were taking about that airlines can flag its passengers and then they can`t fly anymore. I wounder what are the possible reasons that one can end to such no-fly list? Do different airlines exchange no-fly lists and what can one do against wrong flagging?

Comment: Drunk. Harassing. Insulting. Violent. Unclean. Smoking...

Comment: Note that airline-specific bans are different from no-fly lists maintained by governments. Airlines are not in the habit of denying themselves business; a passenger would need to be guilty of some bad behavior to attract a ban. This is true of any business; a supermarket or restaurant could also refuse to do business with someone if he has shown himself to be a liability.

Answer (score 7):

Airlines are private companies and they're free to do, or not do, business with whoever they want, as long as they comply with local discrimination law. If you cause serious disruption to a flight, for example by being violent or obnoxiously drunk or harrassing the crew or your fellow passengers, the airline can decide that it doesn't want to do business with you again and refuse to sell tickets to you or allow you to board. Just as if you were violent or obnoxiously drunk or harassing the staff or other customers of a shop, restaurant or any other business. Except that such things are generally taken as being more serious in the air because you're in a confined space and, much though they might want to, they can't just open the door and throw you out at 30,000ft.

Comment: Although I’m sure about 100 % of all cabin crew members have, at at least one point in their career, wished they could just open the door and throw somebody out ;)